# Displaying SharePoint List View in a ASPX file

Tags: 2007, calendar

**The Situation**

I have a SharePoint 2007 List with a Calendar View. I need to display this View in a custom ASPX page as marked 'Place code here to view SharePoint View of List X' in the following code.

How do I go about it?

**The Code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain">

// Place code here to view SharePoint View of List X

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea">
    The Page Title in Title Area    
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle">
    The Page Title
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would try and do is to create the List View how you want it to appear onto a web part page, then open that web part page in SharePoint Designer. You should be able to see the ListViewWebPart tag in there - copy it out and dump it into the PlaceHolderMain content tag.

Comment: But it seems to have an error saying about tag issue. I searched the internet and it also mention need to create a web.config file. Appreciate if you can provide more details / guidance on this.

Comment: What reference did you read about creating a web.config file? That seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example I've ripped out of a more complex page from a rather old project. I'm not sure if it'll work without tweaking because I don't have a SharePoint 2007 virtual machine at my disposal currently, but it should get you started.

Add this onto your page head:

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %><%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="wssawc" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System" %> <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %> <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI" %> <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" %> <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" %>
```

Put this somewhere at the top of the page:

```
<script runat="server">

private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string listID = "PlaceYourListGuidHere";
    string viewID = "PlaceYourViewGuidHere";

    ListView renderView = new ListView();
    renderView.ListId = listID;
    renderView.ViewId = viewID;

    this.Page.Controls.FindControl("PlaceHolderMain").Controls.FindControl("idRenderView").Controls.Add(renderView);

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

    using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
    {
        renderView.RenderControl(writer);
    }
}

</script>
```

And this inside your placeholder:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="idRenderView" runat="server" />
```

**Update**: Cleaned up the code a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to add a web part zone and drop in the list web part or a data view web part.